# Placeholders not getting resolved on @SpringBootTest

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot unit test that is set up like so:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = Config.class)   
class ConfigTest {
    
    @Test
    void getMeasurement_returnsValues() {
        Map<String, String> result = configs.getMeasurement();
        assertTrue(!result.isEmpty());
    }
}
```

Config.class:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:config.properties")
public class Config {

    @Value("#{${Measurement}}")
    private Map<String, String> measurement;
}
```

config.properties:

```
Measurement = {"key": "${val}"}
```

Here's what baffles me: why does the unit test run fine?  I inspect the `result` map, and the entry's value shows up as "${val}".  I thought it would fail due to Spring not being able to find an assigned value for the `val` parameter?  Meanwhile, application startup does fail for this reason, even though both the unit test and the real Config reference the same `config.properties` file.  What is `@SpringBootTest` doing differently such that it is ignoring the placeholder resolution?

Resulting error on application startup:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'val' in value "{"key": "${val}"}"
```

Comment: could it be that config.properties is under `test/resources`?

Answer (score 0):

Your test runs fine because `assertTrue(!result.isEmpty())` fails only in the case your `result` map is empty and that is not your case because the map contains the association `"key","${val}"`.

The `Could not resolve placeholder 'val' in value "{"key": "${val}"}"` message exception indicates that no `val` property exists in the [`Environment`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html) in which your application is running, to solve the issue you can add the property `val = yourvalue` to your application.properties file.